# Linux shell script delete specific contents in file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have one file called abc.csv, its format is:

```
aa,size:12
bb,size:13
cc,size:3
```

I want to delete size: , and the file will become like this:

```
aa,12
bb,13
cc,3
```

Can anyone tell me how to use shell script to perform this task?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sed` easily for this task:

`sed -i -- 's/size://' abc.csv`

`s/size://` is a simple regex that says replace `size:` with `<blank>`.

Comment: Perfect ! It works on me. Thank You so much. :)

Answer (score 5):

Below is a useful alternative command for Unix users whose version of sed does not support the `-i` flag (such as Solaris -- and also OS X, which ships with BSD `sed` by default).

```
sed 's/size://' abc.csv > tmpfile; mv tmpfile abc.csv
```

The `g` option at the end of the sed command is not required in your specific example, because 'size:' doesn't appear more than once per line.

**EDIT:**  For smaller files, you could also store the updated content in a variable, in order to avoid creating an unnecessary temporary file:

```
new="$(sed 's/size://' abc.csv)"; echo "$new" > abc.csv
```

This method would also *allow the ability* to echo the `"$new"` variable (updated file) to STDOUT for sanity checking purposes before overwriting the original file.